# how can i make a textfield read only in grails?

Tags: grails, textfield

how can i make a textfield read only in grails.

I tried with readonly attribute on textfield as below but its not working.

```
<g:textField name="fname" size="14px"  id="fname" value="${patient.fname}" readonly="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not allows readonly, try disabled="true"

Comment: Not a valid option as `disabled` and `readonly` are different things.

Answer (score 20):

If you use disabled="true" the value will not actually be submitted in the form, so the `<g:field/>` tag should be used.

For example,

```
<g:field type="text" name="name" readonly="readonly" value="${instance.?name}"/>
```

More info [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/field.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use readonly="readonly"