# Grails : Using select tag of grails with disabled property set to true ignores the value

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu

I need to disable a select element in grails depending on its value. The problem is when I started to add the disable property something is quite wrong with the code.

An example is when the form is sent to the backend, its as if there is no value for that select element and the value sent is null. But, when I checked the DOM, there is a selected attribute in the element. I tried to remove that disabled property because I have a feeling that it has something to do with the bug that I'm encountering and I was right because after removing it, everything worked correctly again.

this is the select tag

```
<g:select name="detail-entryNameId"
value="${journalEntryName.savingId}"
from="${journalEntryNameInstanceList}"
optionKey="savingId"
optionValue="displayName"
readonly="${journalEntryInstance.paymentMade}"
/>
```

One more thing about this element is that it can occur as many as possible, which means I have a table and in every row, that element exist so I cannot simply manipulate it.

I've also read in this post [how can i make a textfield read only in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798558/how-can-i-make-a-textfield-read-only-in-grails) that "*If you use disabled="true" the value will not actually be submitted in the form, so the `<g:field/>` tag should be used.*" which proves that disable attribute affects the value of the element.

How can I disable the select element and at the same time, still get its value correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in HTML the mere existence of the *disabled* attribute disables the tag. The value of the attribute (true/false) is ignored.

In such cases the solution is to use an `<g:if>` to create the tag with or without the *disabled* attribute according to a condition.

In your case, since you want the value even when the tag is disabled you can add a `<g:hiddenField>` with the same *name* and value as the disabled *select*.