# How to make text field uneditable?

Tags: javascript, gsp

I have a GSP textField to which I have assigned a datePicker class. I want the user to be not able to write in the field, only to select the date from the field.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
My code is

```
<g:textField name="referralDate" class="required datePicker copyPastePrevent" value="${dateDisplayFormat(date: note?.referralDate)}"/>
```

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: [take a look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798558/how-can-i-make-a-textfield-read-only-in-grails)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting **readonly** at the end of the textfield tag.

```
<g:textField name="referralDate" class="required datePicker copyPastePrevent" value="${dateDisplayFormat(date: note?.referralDate)}" readonly/>
```

or try **disabled="true"**

```
<g:textField name="referralDate" class="required datePicker copyPastePrevent" value="${dateDisplayFormat(date: note?.referralDate)}" disabled="true"/>
```

or **readonly="readonly"**

```
<g:textField name="referralDate" class="required datePicker copyPastePrevent" value="${dateDisplayFormat(date: note?.referralDate)}" readonly="readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting readonly attribute

```
<g:textField name="referralDate" class="required datePicker copyPastePrevent" value="${dateDisplayFormat(date: note?.referralDate)}"/>
```

and if datepicker stops working then try following with it

```
$( ".datePicker" ).focus(function() {
    $('.datePicker').datepicker();
    $('.datePicker').datepicker('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one you should have to use the

```
 <g:field/>
```

tag. if your using **disabled="true"** its not submitting the form.

```
<g:field type="text" name="referralDate" readonly="readonly" value="${dateDisplayFormat(date: note?.referralDate)}"/>
```